# Why does the do-while loop never ends?

Tags: c

I am making a text-based game. One of the things I take input is a Class of the players which needs to be a specific character. I do this for each of the existing number of players that they have input(that is the pnum variable).

```
typedef struct players {
  char class, upgrade1, upgrade2, upgrade3;
  int secondwarD, secondwarS;
  int funds; 
} players;

struct players p[pnum];

for(i=0;i<pnum;i++) {
    do {
      printf("Player %d insert your class:\n", i+1);
      p[i].class=getc(stdin);
    } while(p[i].class!='c' || p[i].class!='t' || p[i].class!='a' || p[i].class!='d');
}
```

Unfortunately it gets stuck on the do+while loop for the same player despite me inserting one of the possible characters. Its a simple thing but I wasn't able to find an existing question that matches this. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How do you get `pnum`?

Comment: you need && not ||. Think: if class is 't' then it is not 'c' so your while is always true

Comment: It's time to learn about the [`switch` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug a simple program. Either get an IDE with a debugger, or add some more printfs into your code to see the other variable values.  Don't you mean to do an "&&" of the p[i].class values?

Comment: Also you don't need two loops to iterate over your `players` array.

Comment: I think he do @woz because he needs to make sure input is ok.

Comment: @Yonlif you can achieve it by using just one loop and adding an increment condition (`if (condition) i++`)

Comment: indeed, it was && and not ||, like i said, simple, but its a very specific question

Comment: If you're looking to make games, consider, at the absolute least, using something like [Curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) to make an interactive text-mode application. One of the first things you should get a handle on is how to work with a simple event-loop and make an event-driven program.

Comment: Well you are right @woz it's just that some people prefer to do not mess with the indexing inside of a for loop

Comment: Don't you need to malloc stuff?

Comment: @Yonlif that's why a `while` loop would be great for it. Also it'd make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the ||(ORs) by &&(ANDs)

```
for(i=0;i<pnum;i++) {
    do {
      printf("Player %d insert your class:\n", i+1);
      p[i].class=getc(stdin);
    } while(p[i].class!='c' && p[i].class!='t' && p[i].class!='a' && p[i].class!='d');
}
```

Imagine the user enter `char t`. If it were OR instead of AND, first condition would be true which is enough to proceed with the loop again. But if it's AND all conditions needs to be TRUE in order to proceed with the loop. Since second will be FALSE, so the do-while loop shall terminate.

In short,

```
(p[i].class!='c' || p[i].class!='t' || p[i].class!='a' || p[i].class!='d')
```

would mean that **ANY** of them being **TRUE** is sufficient to **PROCEED** with the loop

but,

```
(p[i].class!='c' && p[i].class!='t' && p[i].class!='a' && p[i].class!='d')
```

would mean that **ANY** of them being **FALSE** is sufficient to **STOP** the loop